# SQL Temporary Table or Select

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, datatable

I've got a problem with `MySQL` `select` statement.
I have a table with different `Department` and statuses, there are 4 statuses for every department, but for each month there are not always every single status but I would like to show it in the analytics graph that there is '0'.

I have a problem with `select` statement that it shows only existing statuses ( of course :D ).
Is it possible to create temporary table with all of the `Departments` , `Statuses` and `amount of statuses` as 0, then update it by values from other select?

Select statement and screen how it looks in perfect situation, and how it looks in bad situation :

```
SELECT utd.Departament,uts.statusDef as statusoforder,Count(uts.statusDef) as Ilosc_Statusow 
FROM ur_tasks_details utd 
INNER JOIN ur_tasks_status uts on utd.StatusOfOrder = uts.statusNR 
WHERE month = 'Sierpien' 
GROUP BY uts.statusDef,utd.Departament
```

[image]

Perfect scenario, now bad scenario :

[image]

I've tried with "union" statements but i don't know if there is a possibility to take only "the highest value" for every department.

example :

[image]

I've also heard about
With CTE tables, but I don't really get how to use it. Would love to get some tips on it!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use an outer join.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows you want.  Then use a `left join` and aggregation to bring in the data:

```
select d.Departament, uts.statusDef as statusoforder,
       Count(uts.statusDef) as Ilosc_Statusow
from (select distinct utd.Departament 
      from ur_tasks_details utd
     ) d cross join
     ur_tasks_status uts left join
     ur_tasks_details utd
     on utd.Departament = d.Departament and
        utd.StatusOfOrder = uts.statusNR and
        utd.month = 'Sierpien'
group by uts.statusDef, d.Departament;
```

The first subquery should be your source of all the departments.

I also suspect that `month` is in the details table, so that should be part of the `on` clause.

Comment: Hi, i tried your select statement but it returns the same data as my does. It gives back only existing ones as it counts statusdef, but i wanted to create a table with all of the departments and value "0" and then combine it with real one and just switch zeros with good numbers. 

Select statement with 0 instead of counting : 
SELECT  utd.Departament,uts.statusDef as statusoforder,0 as Ilosc_Statusow 
from ur_tasks_details utd inner join ur_tasks_status uts on utd.StatusOfOrder = uts.statusNR 
where month = 'Sierpien' group by uts.statusDef,utd.Departament
order by departament

Comment: Select statement with just a few statuses and departaments 
SELECT utd.Departament,uts.statusDef as statusoforder,Count(uts.statusDef) as Ilosc_Statusow 
from ur_tasks_details utd inner join ur_tasks_status uts on utd.StatusOfOrder = uts.statusNR 
where month = 'Wrzesien' group by uts.statusDef,utd.Departament